# Optimizing code of metafeatures generation

Tags: python, optimization, text-classification

I'm working on text classification. I've written this code to generate KNN meta-features extracted from the original TF-IDF representations. KNN meta-features are obtained by selecting the k nearest documents from each class for a given document. This image illustrates an example of how to generate KNN meta-features, where the colored circles represent the documents belonging to three different classes, and the number of neighbors chosen here is k=2.
[image: knn meatfeatures]

The code above works perfectly with a small dataset, but the computational complexity has increased significantly with a larger dataset.

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
def scipy_cdist(point1, point2):
    distance = cdist(np.array([point1]), np.array([point2]), metric='euclidean')[0][0]
    return distance
# calculating the sorted distances for one document with others
def get_dist(train, test_row,y_train):
    distances = list()
    dist_ord=list()   
    for i in range(len(train)):
        dist = euclidean_distance(test_row, train[i])
        distances.append((train[i],y_train[i], dist))
    #sorted by classes then by distance
    distances.sort(key=itemgetter(1,2)) 
    return distances#,dist_ord

#calculating distances for all documents
all_distances_train=list()
for i in range(len(x_train)):
    d= get_dist(x_train, x_train[i],y_train)
    all_distances_train.append(d)      

#calculating a class neighbors(for one document)
def class_neighbors(dist,c,k):
    n=list()
    for i in range(len(dist)):
        if dist[i][1]==c and dist[i][2]!=0:
           n.append(dist[i][2])
    c_neighbors=n[:k] 
    return c_neighbors
#calculating all the classes  neighbors(for one document)
def get_all_neighbors(distances,y_data,k):
    classes=np.unique(y_data)
    all_neighbors=list()
    for c in range (len(classes)):
       n=class_neighbors(distances,c,k)
       all_neighbors.extend(n)
    return all_neighbors

#generating knnL2 metafeatures

def get_knnL2(all_distances,y_data,k):
    knnL2=list()
    for i in range(len(all_distances)):
        neighbors=get_all_neighbors(all_distances[i],y_data,k)
        knnL2.append(neighbors)
    return knnL2  

#generating knnL2_train metaFeatures
knnL2_train=get_knnL2(all_distances_train,y_train,2)
knnL2_train=np.array(knnL2_train)
#display  
print(knnL2_train)

#.......................knnl2_test
#calculating distances for all documents
all_distances_test=list()
for i in range(len(x_test)):
    d= get_dist(x_train, x_test[i],y_train)
    all_distances_test.append(d)      

#generating knnL2-test metafeatures
knnL2_test=get_knnL2(all_distances_test,y_train,2)
knnL2_test=np.array(knnL2_test)
#display
print(knnL2_test)
```

I've tried multiple optimization attempts, and this is the best version I could come up with.Can anyone show me how I can optimize this code?

Comment: I can point out some micro-optimizations that won't make a difference, but your algorithm is inherently `O(N^2)` and isn't going to scale.  The only way to reduce the time is to figure out a way to reduce the number of connections.  Can you group the classes separately?

Comment: Yes, the classes are already labeled.It's a supervised machine learning task. I've already implemented some optimizations, but the only one that makes a difference is calculating the Euclidean distance using 'cdist' from 'scipy'. It's really fast.

Comment: When you have `for i in range(len(train)):` you should do `for t in train:` and replace `train[i]` with `t`.  That saves lookup time.  That applies to almost all of your `for` loops.

Comment: It is hard to know what is slow in this code (especially since we cannot run it). I think the first thing to do is to *profile it* (e.g. using cprofile). I expect `scipy_cdist` to be quite inefficient if `point1` and `point2` are scalar : creating 2 temporary arrays and calling a SciPy function to compute only few mathematical basic operations seems very expensive.